# How does .NET digital signing work?

Tags: c#, digital-signature

I'm rather confused at how strong key signing for a .NET assembly works.. I signed with a strong name my .NET assembly by inserting a password and having a .pfx file generated...

how is this supposed to protect my dll? Can someone explain this to me in simple terms? I'm a newbie with digital signing and you'll have to take a BIG step back to have me understand this

Comment: Signing with a certificate and strong naming are completely different and neither protects your dll. Which are you asking about?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm asking about verifying that I issued a .NET assembly file to a user and not somebody else with another file

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> I'm a newbie with digital signing and you'll have to take a BIG step back to have me understand this

Ok, let's take a big step back and ask some more basic questions then. I'll boldface every word that has a precise meaning.

> What is the purpose of a security system?

To protect a **resource** (a pile of gold doubloons) against the **threat of successful attack** (theft) by a **hostile** party (a thief) who seeks to take advantage of a **vulnerability** (an unlocked window). (*)

> How does .NET's Code Access Security work in general?

This is a sketch of the .NET 1.0 security system; it is rather complicated and has been more or less replaced by a somewhat simpler system, but the basic features are the same.

Every **assembly** presents **evidence** to the runtime.  A domain administrator, machine administrator, user and appdomain creator each may create a **security policy**.  A policy is a statement of what **permissions** are granted when a certain piece of evidence is present.  When an assembly attempts to perform a potentially dangerous operation -- that is, an operation that might be a threat to a resource -- the runtime **demands** that the permission be granted. If the evidence is insufficient to grant that permission then the operation fails with an exception.

So for example, suppose an assembly presents the evidence "I was just downloaded from the internet", and the policy says "code downloaded from the internet gets permission to run and access the printer" and that code then attempts to write to `C:\Windows\System32`. The permission was not granted because of insufficient evidence, and so the operation fails. The resource -- the contents of the system directory -- are protected from tampering.

> What is the purpose of signing an assembly with a digital certificate that I got from VeriSign?

An assembly signed with a digital certificate presents evidence to the runtime describing the certificate that was used to sign the assembly.  An administrator, user or application may modify security policy to state that this evidence can grant a particular permission.

The evidence presented by an assembly signed with a digital certificate is: this assembly was signed by someone who possessed the private key associated with this certificate, and *moreover*, the identity of the certificate holder has been verified by VeriSign.

Digital certificates enable the user of your software to make a trust decision on the basis of your identity being verified by a trusted third party.

> So how does that protect my DLL?

It doesn't. Your DLL is the crowbar that is going to be used to jimmy the window, not the pile of gold coins! Your DLL isn't a resource to be protected in the first place. The user's data is the resource to be protected.  Digital signatures are there to facilitate an existing trust relationship. Your customer trusts you to write code that does what it says on the label. The signature enables them to know that the code they are running really came from you because the identity of the author of the code was verified by a trusted third party.

> Isn't strong naming the same thing then?

No.

Strong naming is similar, in that a strong-named DLL presents cryptographically strong evidence to the runtime that the assembly was signed by a particular private key associated with a particular public key.  But the purpose of strong naming is different. As the term implies, strong naming is about creating a name for an assembly that can only be associated with the real assembly.  Anyone can make a DLL named foo.dll, and if you load foo.dll into memory by its weak name, you'll get whatever DLL is on the machine of that name, regardless of who created it.  But only the owner of the private key corresponding to the public key can make a dll with the strong name `foo, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=03689116d3a4ae33`.

So again, the purpose of strong naming is not *directly* to facilitate a trust relationship between a software provider and a user. The purpose of strong naming is to ensure that a developer who uses your library is *really* using the *specific* version of that library that you *actually released*.

> I notice that VeriSign wasn't a factor in strong naming. Is there no trusted third party?

That's right; with a strong name there is no trusted third party that verifies that the public key associated with a given strong name is actually associated with a particular organization or individual.

This mechanism in digital certificates facilitates a trust relationship because the trusted third party can vouch that the public key really is associated with the trusted organization. Lacking that mechanism, somehow the consumer of a strong name needs to know what the public key of your organization is. How you communicate that to them securely is up to you.

> Are there other implications to the fact that there is no trusted third party when strong naming?

Yes. Suppose for example that someone breaks into your office and steals the computer with the digital certificate private key on it. That attacker can now produce software signed with that key.  But certifying authorities such as VeriSign publish "revocation lists" of known-to-be-compromised certificates. If your customers are up-to-date on downloading revocation lists from their certifying authorities then once you revoke your certificate, they can detect that your software might be from a hostile third party. You then have the difficult task of getting a new cert, re-signing all your code, and distributing it to customers, but at least there is some mechanism in place for dealing with the situation.

Not so with strong names. There is no central certifying authority to appeal to for a list of compromised strong names. If your strong name private key is stolen, you are out of luck. There is no revocation mechanism.

> I took a look at my default security policy and it says that (1) any code on the local machine is fully trusted, and (2) any code on the local machine that is strong-named by Microsoft is fully trusted. Isn't that redundant?

Yes. This way if the first policy is made more restrictive then the second policy still applies. It seems reasonable that an administrator might want to lower the trust level of installed software without lowering the trust level of the assemblies that must be fully trusted because they keep the security system itself working.

> But wait a moment, that still seems redundant. Why not set the default policy to "(1) any code on the local machine is trusted (2) any code strong-named by Microsoft is fully trusted"?

Suppose a disaster strikes and the Microsoft private key is compromised. It is stored deep in a vault under building 11, protected by sharks with laser beams, but still, suppose that happened. This would be a disaster of epic proportions because like I just said, there's no revocation system.  If that happened AND the security policy was as you describe then the attacker who has the key can put hostile software *on the internet* that is then fully trusted by the default security policy!  With the security policy as it actually is stated -- requiring both a strong name and a local machine location -- the attacker who has the private key now has to trick the user into downloading and installing it.

This is an example of "defense in depth". Always assume that every other security system has failed, and still do the best to stop the attacker.

As a best practice you should always set a strong name or digital signing policy to include a location.

> So again, strong naming isn't to protect my DLL.

Right. The purpose of the security system is never to protect *you*, the software vendor, or any artifact you produce. It is to protect your customers from attackers who seek to take advantage of the trust relationship between your customers and you. A strong name ensures that code which uses your libraries is really using *your* libraries. It does this by making an extremely convenient mechanism for *identifying* a particular version of a particular DLL.

> Where can I read more?

I've written [an entire short book on the .NET 1.0 security system](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1861007477) but it is now out of print, and superseded by the new simplified system anyways.

Here are some more articles I've written on this subject:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/03/what-s-the-difference-part-five-certificate-signing-vs-strong-naming.aspx

http://ericlippert.com/2009/06/04/alas-smith-and-jones/

---

(*) Security systems have other goals than preventing a successful attack; a good security system will also provide non-repudiable evidence of a successful attack, so that the attacker can be tracked down and prosecuted after the attack. These features are outside the scope of this discussion.

Comment: I think this suits more what I wanted to learn: so if I tell the users "I have this public key token", they will be able to learn (by verifying on the assembly they have) if they have MY assembly or another one's one.

Comment: @DavidKernin: Correct. Notice that this implies that the communication channel between you and your users is secure. Suppose Evil Twin David Kernin tells them "don't listen to that guy; the real public key token is this one". How do they know whether to believe you or your evil twin? That's for you and your customers to work out.  A certificate, by contrast, puts the burden of telling you and your evil twin apart on VeriSign, or whatever certifying authority your user chooses to trust.

Comment: Of course, you still have the burden of telling Verisign and Verisign's evil twin apart.  Usually the operating system comes with a certificate.  So, you still have the burden of telling OS and evil OS apart.  And so forth.  Eric Lippert tells a similar story in [Keep it Secret, Keep it Safe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx).

Comment: i know this gona sound strange but i wish you would dumb it down more. with regards to both the digital certificate and strong-named. As the only thing which was clear was that its to protect the clients machine and not your .dll but what wasn't made clear is how is the dll verified? do i have to submit each version to a trusted issuer? same for the strong-named.. what? maybe i should read it again but would be handy if its was dumbed down in terms of how these would be done for say x dll. You explain why its done perfectly but how its done...I love pictures(diagrams) i guess.

Comment: @Seabizkit: If you have *specific* questions then your best bet is to ask a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5):

In brief, one of the main purposes is to protect against loading an assembly by the CLR after it has been changed. For example, you ship a software with a DLL, someone could reflect it, change the code, and build it again, and let your program load it thinking it is your dll. To protect against that, a hash is computed when you build your dll and stored with it. At runtime, when the CLR loads the DLL, it computes the hash again and compares against what is stored with the DLL, if the DLL is still intact, then it should match and CLR would load it, otherwise it would not load.

This should give you a very good explanation with more details:

http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/dot-net-assemblies-and-strong-name-signature/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: And what is the pfx file generated by visual studio? Is there any way to publish a public key and say "use this to verify that the dll is the one I created" ?